# Start an event only when the previous one has completely finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the function below, I would like the last event `$('.bg-contact').addClass('activated');` to start when the previous event has completely finished. As of now, everything happens at once. How can I make sure `.bg-contact` gets the `activated` class added only after everything above it has already happened?

```
function contactFadeIn() {
    $('#contact').addClass('activated');
    $('#contact-info').removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    $('.bg-contact').addClass('activated');
}
```

**Edit**

```
function contactFadeIn() {
    $('#contact').addClass('activated');
    $('#contact-info').removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass('animated fadeInUp').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () { 
        $('.bg-contact').addClass('activated');
    });;
}
```

Comment: adding or removing a class is as close to instantaneous as you're going to get - ie, there is no callback for them. JQuery animations tend to be chainable so that an action can be performated at the end of the animation.

Comment: @Jamiec: CSS transitions are probably in mind here.

Comment: Do you have some animation with these classes? If yes, please update it with your full animation duration. If not, I don't get what you mean by completely finished. It will run line by line, executing each add/remove class.

Comment: @sixfingeredman I agree, but nothing in the question specifies that.

Comment: @sixfingeredman Yes, you're correct. Sorry, should have specified.

Comment: @Jamiec: Class names like `fadeOutUp` & `fadeInUp` were strong clues :)

Comment: If possible , can post `event` types , expected results of events ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have css transitions in mind here.

If so, then use the `transitionEnd` event to schedule an event to take place when the transition is done.

Comment: Can I just add that onto the end of the second line like this? `$('#contact-info').removeClass('fadeOutUp').addClass('animated fadeInUp').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () { //my event handler });`? Edit: Looks like I can. :)

Comment: @J82: Typically you'd bind an event handler once so that it runs every time an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to do and the following worked great....

```
//update quantity and animate
$(".quan").addClass("scaled").delay(200).queue(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("scaled");
    $(this).dequeue();
});`
```

Comment: This does mean you need to maintain the durations in two places though (CSS and code).

Comment: i guess so... in my css I have a transition of 0.1s so the background and size of hte object changes. All the Javascript does is ensure the class changes, then adds a delay before removing. What I found though was that just using the transition didn't work as the Javascript was changing the class too quickly.